# Anime/show about elemental gems and knights?

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this around 7-8 years ago on Toonami/Cartoon Network and I'm still not quite sure it was an anime or an animated TV show.
I watched this series completely in Spanish since that's my main language but sadly I was too young to remember anything else about the animation style or quotes from it.
The opening is the thing I'm less sure of but it basically recapped the story, and it was something like...

- a king having a belt (a belt? could be something else) that had elemental gems on it,
- the antagonist tried to get the gems so the king hid the gems all around the world, now the villain's trying to get it back and the heroes are trying to get them so the villain doesn't get them.

I remember 3 episodes, to an extent,

- The first was the heroes being trapped on quicksand, and they end up meeting with an old man and an old woman that save them, they spoke in gibberish and gave them food and a place to stay. Some of the protagonists were suspicious about this but were obviously told they were exaggerating. Eventually they found out the old people were speaking backwards and were trying to eat them, the old couple transform into monsters and they defeat them.
- Another episode is the heroes looking for the water gem and finding themselves on a beach with a huge castle floating right in the middle of the water. They tried their best to reach it (not sure how they did?) only to have one of them reach the castle and find a huge blue dragon with the gem on it's forehead.
- The next episode is just the rest of the characters getting to the castle and defeating the dragon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like [*Deltora Quest*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_(series)). There was a previous question about it:
[Cartoon Network show. Monster hunting. Dark theme. Monsters looked to be done by CGI](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186382/cartoon-network-show-monster-hunting-dark-theme-monsters-looked-to-be-done-by/186386#186386)

Comment: OP here, sumelic got it right! I was even able to find the exact episodes I was talking about (sadly I made some mistakes but I'm glad they got it right anyways!) been looking for this for about 6 years now, thanks to everyone that helped :0!

Answer (score 4):

This sounds extremely similar to [Ronin Warriors/Legendary Armor Samurai Troopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronin_Warriors). It *was* aired on Toonami, and it has roughly the plot you described: a very bad fellow from the past is vanquished by an ancient hero and his armor is split into pieces and sent around the globe for safekeeping. Big bad returns in the modern era and seeks his armor, but 5 young warriors stand in his way and anime things ensue:

> Long before Talpa came to conquer Tokyo in modern times, a mystic
>   known as The Ancient One defeated Talpa in battle. The mystic sent
>   Talpa's soul to the Underworld, but the warlord's demonic armor
>   remained in the mortal world. As a precaution against Talpa's possible
>   return, The Ancient One melted down the armor, then remade it into
>   nine separate armors. Five of these armors found their way to the
>   Ronin Warriors; the other four ended up with Talpa's Warlords.

There is an episode with a lake. There is a castle in the sky.

There is armor.

[image: Armor. Told you!]

There is also the [Toonami Wiki entry](http://toonami.wikia.com/wiki/Ronin_Warriors).

There is a [lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ronin_Warriors_episodes) of [info](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/RoninWarriors) out there on the web that should help you confirm/deny/rage at the heavens that this is your series. You can also [watch the whole series](http://www.crunchyroll.com/samurai-troopers) on Crunchyroll.