# Anime where the MC collects magical stones

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw the anime between 2012-2015 I guess?

- The MC was a kind person.
- He probably had black hair and he was about 18.
- The world had magical things and monsters.
- Its opening song had a sound like a bell ringing, as if the reaper's coming...
- The boy collected some magical stones with some allies.
- The last thing I remember was that one of his allies turned into a monster like a werewolf or something at some point.

**Does anyone know the name of this anime**?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

*[Deltora Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_(TV_series))*

> The Shadow Lord, an evil sorcerer and The Lord of Shadows which comes from The Shadowlands, has taken over Deltora by destroying a magical object known as The Belt of Deltora, which is Deltora's only protection against him. Throughout the course of the anime, Lief, Barda and Jasmine travel around the land of Deltora to return the seven gem of the initials of which combine to form DELTORA (hence the name "Deltora Quest") to the belt and save the land. Their first destination is the Forests of Silence.

[Zan](https://deltoraquest.fandom.com/wiki/Zan) is the werewolf.

### Opening theme (opens with a bell sound)

:) This one comes up fairly often, and this is a good default for "fantasy world, seeking magic stones" questions.

Comment: If accepted, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186382/23243