# TV series about a group of friends collecting magical stones, which were then placed in a circle. They fight a big frog at one point

Tags: story-identification, tv, magic

A TV show where there was a group of friends who were collecting special magical stones (each with different color, as I remember) and they had to defeat different monsters to get those stones.

It was a journey and after each episode, it showed how many stones they had and how many they had left to collect. The stones were placed in a circle. Sorry, I don't remember much but the last boss they fought was a big frog.

Comment: Welcome Mladen. Please read our [checklist for story ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and add as much detail as you're able. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as and when. Enjoy the site.

Comment: Yes, in particular it would be helpful to know when you watched this show, when you think it was made, and whether it was live-action or an animation.

Comment: As per the [tour], if someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 9):

It's possible that you might have been watching *[Deltora Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_(TV_series))*.

[image: Deltora Quest front cover]

> The Shadow Lord, an evil sorcerer and The Lord of Shadows which comes from The Shadowlands, has taken over Deltora by destroying a magical object known as The Belt of Deltora, which is Deltora's only protection against him. Throughout the course of the anime, Lief, Barda and Jasmine travel around the land of Deltora to return the seven gem of the initials of which combine to form DELTORA (hence the name "Deltora Quest") to the belt and save the land. Their first destination is the Forests of Silence.

### Opening sequence

One of the later creatures they defeat is [Gellick](https://deltoraquest.fandom.com/wiki/Gellick), an Ooze toad.

[image: Gellick, the Ooze Toad]

### Episode 28:  The Great Gellick!

As per your memories, they do end episodes with an image of what gems they've collected.

[image: Image of the belt with 5 gems filled in and two empty space]

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186382/cartoon-network-show-monster-hunting-dark-theme-monsters-looked-to-be-done-by/186386#186386

Comment: So if the answer is the same as a different question, the question is a duplicate?

Comment: If confirmed, yes.

Comment: @HannoverFist: Reviewing this, it occurred to me that I didn't comment that [this is a bit of a special case for story-identification](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3431/) where we diligently close for it being the same work, but do not close for similar questions.

Answer (score 5):

**Di-Gata Defenders**

Based on the insanely minute amount of information, the show you might be looking for is the Nelvana cartoon Di-Gata Defenders, initially named Power Stone Warriors in development:
https://web.archive.org/web/20100105061946/http://www.digata.com/

Some shared features: the Di-Gata stones; the heroes fight monsters to get them.

The enemies are amphibian:

> But in doing so, they eventually exiled the original inhabitants, the Mortigarians, a race of amphibious snake-like humanoids to live
> under the sea. The people that live in RaDos as of the current timeline are the descendants of these first RaDosians.

A boss beast was called the megalith, a sort of amphibian Cthulhu-ish monstrosity that might sort of get confused for a “giant frog.”

I’m going with it.