# Medieval cartoon with blonde prince wearing blue, searching for 7 magical gems with a knight

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There's this show I watched as a kid but I completely forgot its name.

It starts with a blond prince that literally only wears blue, sent into exile with his parents who are the former king and queen of the realm and their protective knight that wears a crown of some sort.

The prince's parents were burned down, then him and the knight go looking for around 7 gems, that were in each country, that have powers of some sort.

On the way they meet a green, tanned girl who has a survival instinct and is like the rogue in the game. The enemies are usually anything from big ass monsters to giant scorpions.

Comment: Probably a dupe of [A cartoon/anime with a blonde-haired boy with blue eyes and his father(?), they're looking for 7 gems/diamonds](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125181/a-cartoon-anime-with-a-blonde-haired-boy-with-blue-eyes-and-his-father-they/125184)

Comment: With an accepted answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186382/cartoon-network-show-monster-hunting-dark-theme-monsters-looked-to-be-done-by?noredirect=1&lq=1 :)

Comment: @ExternalizationGenocide: If Rand's answer is the correct one, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds a lot like [the answer to a previous question here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/186386/31394), namely the anime TV series ***[Deltora Quest](https://ctrlgeekpod.com/2015/05/14/dvd-review-deltora-quest-collection/)*** (2007). From the linked description (emphasis mine):

> Deltora Quest follows the journeys of Lief, the son of a humble blacksmith, who sets out to fulfill his father’s quest to restore the Belt of Deltora.
>
> In this epic quest to save Deltora from the evil grips of the Shadow Lord, Lief is joined by ex-palace guard Barda and **Jasmine, a wild girl from the Forests of Silence.** Their quest is to **find the seven gems of the Belt of Deltora**: the topaz, ruby, opal, lapis lazuli, emerald, amethyst, and the diamond. **Each gem has a special power hidden in ominous locations around Deltora**, and in order to find these gems, the three friends must face numerous obstacles and perils.
>
> Their adventure is no easy task — the trio must form crucial allies; slay monsters; and tackle obstacles filled with twists, betrayal, and word games in order to survive. Once the Belt is complete and the proper descendant of the first King of Deltora, Adin, wears the belt, the evil tyranny of the Shadow Lord will be forced back to the Shadowlands.

The opening credits (link shamelessly stolen from FuzzyBoots's previous answer):